# How can I install IronAHK on Ubuntu LTS 18.04?

Tags: automation, autokey

I am trying to install Linux equivalent of Autohotkey on Ubuntu LTS 18.04.

a) I have followed the following guide:
[Building IronAHK from source on Ubuntu](https://brendonrobinson.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/building-ironahk-from-source-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/)

I have tried these:

```
sudo apt-get -y install git mono-xbuild libmono-winforms2.0-cil libmono-microsoft-visualbasic8.0-cil mono-vbnc mono-gmcs
git clone https://github.com/polyethene/IronAHK
cd IronAHK
make
sudo make install
sudo chmod +x Deploy/bin/Release/setup.sh
sudo ./Deploy/bin/Release/setup.sh install
```

After the installation has completed. I have tried to run the program with the following command but I am getting runtime version problem. How can I fix this problem?

```
q@q-ABRA-A5-V12-1:~/IronAHK$ ironahk [--gui]
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
Specified file path not found.
```

I think that the reason for this problem is mono runtime version.I have installed the last version of the mono like the following:

```
sudo apt-get -y install git mono-xbuild
```

But It doesn't work with the latest stable version of Mono. I have done some research but I cannot find which version of mono required for IronAHK.

Any idea or recommendation appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IronAHK is not maintained anymore and very old (see https://github.com/Paris/IronAHK). I do not think you will be able to get it to work. May I suggest to try AutoKey (https://github.com/autokey/autokey), which is based on Python but can do a lot of things AHK can do as well as many other stuff.

Comment: Hi. I ended up using VirtualBox Windows on Linux. I don't have time for converting Autohotkey script to Autokey script but thanks for the suggestion.